Дефисы между буквами
Ошибкой ли будет писать так?
Де-вя-нос-то 
Т-р-и

Вроде встречал подобное написание в книжках, типа авторская пунктуация.
Какую функцию здесь выполняет дефис? Или это тире?

О таком (дефисном) написании интересно и доходчив сказано в ПАС:

§ 113. Дефис находит применение также в специальных случаях.
3. В любых текстах (чаще в художественных и публицистических) дефис может использоваться в выразительных целях:
а) для выделения (смыслового и произносительного) какой-либо части слова, напр.: Сто — невест тебе! Все — с запястьями! Без-ответственно. Бес-препятственно (Цвет.); Что звалось «само-лётом», не летало само (Рожд.)...
б) для передачи произношения по слогам с разными целями (произнесение говорящим незнакомого слова, смысловое выделение важного слова и др.), напр.: ...Только всё-таки это был очаровательный сон, о-ча-ро-ва-тельный сон!.. (Дост.)...
в) для передачи протяжного звучания гласных, раскатистого р и других особенностей произношения, напр.: ...Ну о-о-очень навязчивая реклама! (из газеты); Это было р-р-р-революционно!..

• Пример из любимого "Собачьего сердца":

...звуки хитрой вариации «Светит месяц» смешивались в голове Филиппа Филипповича со словами заметки в ненавистную кашу. Дочитав, он сухо плюнул через плечо и машинально запел сквозь зубы:
— Све-е-етит месяц… Све-е-етит месяц… Светит месяц… Тьфу, прицепилась, вот окаянная мелодия!

• Примеры из Нацкорпуса
Тур долго не мог понять, что она хочет притащить, покуда Ивон не передала по буквам: с-т-о-л-б (Юрий Сенкевич. Путешествие длиною в жизнь).
И блюдечко завертелось, выстраивая по буквам: «Т-в-а-р-ь!» (Дина Рубина. На солнечной стороне улицы).
— Го-ло-дранец, — повторила по слогам старшенькая (Н. В. Нестерова. Лялька, или Квартирный вопрос).
Но она всё равно засунула её в карман своего платья вместе с другими вещами и только после этого, вспомнив про гостя, сказала по слогам: «Тра-твуй-те» (Евгений Чижов. Перевод с подстрочника).
Но слово сразу не далось и, опять с трудом настроив фокус, дед по слогам прочитал: — «Контра-цеп-тив» (В. А. Мухарьямов. Брагины).
• Какое именно звучание числа (слова) вам надо передать на письме, так и записывайте.
Нашелся, как мне кажется, интересный пример (см.):
Учительница показывала на каждую кучку оленей, для ясности отгибала на пальцах, потом громко говорила по-русски: «п-я-т-ь». И ученики повторяли хором: «п-я-т-ь», «п-ят-с-ь», «п-е-т-с-ь», — с разными акцентами.

У вас собачье сердце любимое, обычно Швейка все наизусть учат и по 100 раз перечитывают)
